# How to add different random values to n elements of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to add random values to a specific amount of values in a numpy array to mutate weights of my neural network. For example, 2 of the values in this array

```
[ [0 1 2]
  [3 4 5]
  [6 7 8] ]
```

are supposed to be mutated (i. e. a random value between -1 and 1 is added to them). The result may look something like this then:

```
[ [0   0.7 2]
  [3   4   5]
  [6.9 7   8]]
```

I would prefer a solution without looping, as my real problem is a little bigger than a 3x3 matrix and looping usually is inefficient.

Comment: Creating an array with random values is covered quite thoroughly on line, as is adding two arrays.  Just where are you stuck?  Post the code with a *specific* problem, not a discussion on things you might try.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I thought I had stated my problem clearly. I now removed my first (inefficient and inelegant) approach to solve this problem, which may have been distracting. I am sorry, but I could not find any advice on how to create an array filled with zeros except for a certain amount of random values, maybe I just don't know the right term to search for though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way based on [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html?highlight=random%20choice#numpy.random.choice) -

```
def add_random_n_places(a, n):
    # Generate a float version
    out = a.astype(float)

    # Generate unique flattened indices along the size of a
    idx = np.random.choice(a.size, n, replace=False)

    # Assign into those places ramdom numbers in [-1,1)
    out.flat[idx] += np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=n)
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [89]: a # input array
Out[89]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [90]: add_random_n_places(a, 2)
Out[90]: 
array([[0.        , 1.        , 2.        ],
       [2.51523009, 4.        , 5.        ],
       [6.        , 7.        , 8.36619255]])

In [91]: add_random_n_places(a, 4)
Out[91]: 
array([[0.67792859, 0.84012682, 2.        ],
       [3.        , 3.71209157, 5.        ],
       [6.        , 6.46088001, 8.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.random.rand(3,3)` to create a 3x3 matrix with [0,1) random values.
To get (-1,1) values try `np.random.rand(3,3) - np.random.rand(3,3)` and add this to a matrix you want to mutate.